# Pyinstaller with Subprocess.popen fails as exe

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, pyinstaller

I am struggling with my implementation of subprocess when created exe with pyInstaller.

I have a program that has a gui (tkinter) where multiple buttons have their subprocess.popen(). there is a command over ssh sent to a network device which needs some time to finish.

In pyCharm this works smooth. 
When I create the exe with pyInstaller, I get the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
  File "gui.py" in line 197 in wrapper
  File "subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
key not found: process1
```

The corresponding code snipped of gui.py line 197 is:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', r'commands/pec_cmd.py', 
       str(cmd), pec_ip, '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
       startupinfo=subprocess.STARTUPINFO(), env=os.environ, 
       stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

later on I store the process in a dict, which is initialized earlier with subproccesses = {}:

```
subprocesses['process' + str(i)] = proc
```

Any idea or help why I get this FileNotFoundError? 
When run from PyCharm it works, but as soon as the exe is created (--onedir and --onefile tried), it fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify which file isn't found `python.exe` or `commands/pec_cmd.py`.

You could try to run the subprocess within the current shell: `subprocess.Popen(... shell=True)` or use full paths for subprocess

```
subprocess.Popen(['c:/python/python.exe', r'c:/whateverPath/commands/pec_cmd.py'])
```

But you still depend on a pre-installed Python interpreter:
Imagine you want to run your application/exe another computer, which hasn't Python installed the subprocesses will fail or you will always need to install Python.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Maurice Meyer. I was not afraid of the fact, that then still python needs to be installed. So I changed it to call a exe: 
Instead of calling `subprocess.popen("python", commands/pec_cmd.py", ...)` it is now working when calling `subprocess.popen("pec_cmd.exe", ...)` directly with the exe instead of the python with the script pec_cmd.py.